# Comparing MouseEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events

I have more than one Event Listener that calls a specific function, and I want to add if statements to check what event is being passed. How can I do that?
I tried a simple comparison like:

```
if(evt == MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER)
```

But it will give an error because I comparing a MouseEvent object and a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `type` property of the event:

```
if(evt.type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER)
```